# tkinter Loop Through List On Key Press

Tags: python, tkinter

Im am trying to create a command history with the tkinter Entry widget and Up/Down arrow keys. It is for a very basic MUD client that I am trying to come up with in my spare time.

```
# The list that hold the last entered commands.
self.previousCommands = []

# Binding the up arrow key to the Entry widget.
self.view.Tabs.tab1.E.bind('<Up>', self.checkCommandHistory)

# The function that should cycle through the commands.
def checkCommandHistory(self, event):
    comm = self.previousCommands[-1]
    self.view.Tabs.tab1.E.delete(0, END)
    self.view.Tabs.tab1.E.insert(0, comm)
```

Basically what I am trying to do is cycle through a list that contains the history of the last entered commands by using the up and down arrow keys. This behavior is common in most MUD clients but I cannot see exactly how this is achieved.

Using the code above I am able to bind the Up arrow key press to the Entry widget and on pressed it does insert the last entered command. If I were to keep pressing the up arrow key I would like it to keep cycling through the last entered commands in the list.

Comment: Looks OK, and **what** is your Question?

Comment: Say I have a list containing ['dret', 'drci', 'egad']. I was wondering if anyone had any idea how I would cycle though that list and populate the Entry widget using the Up arrow key. Using the code above I am able to get the last element in the list. I would like to then press the Up arrow again, and get the 2nd last element in the list. Up arrow a third time, and get the 3rd last element. I was hoping someone could give me an idea on how I would achieve the result. So to simplify, How do I cycle the elements in a list by pressing the Up arrow key bound to Entry widget in tkinter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a non-OOP based version.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

history = []
history_index = -1

def runCommand(event):
    command = cmd.get()
    print("Running command: {}".format(command))
    cmd.set("")
    history.append(command)
    history_index = -1
    print(history)

def cycleHistory(event):
    global history_index
    if len(history):
        try:
            comm = history[history_index]
            history_index -= 1
        except IndexError:
            history_index = -1
            comm = history[history_index]
        cmd.set(comm)

cmd = tk.StringVar(root)
e = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=cmd)
e.grid()
e.bind("<Return>",runCommand)
e.bind("<Up>",cycleHistory)
e.focus()

root.mainloop()
```

Basically, you just need to keep an record of which item from history you should show next time the user presses the up arrow. I use the `history_index` field to do this. `history_index` is set to -1 initially and each time it is accessed it is decremented by 1.

I use the `except IndexError` exception to reset the index to -1 once there is no more history to read from the list and to start from the beginning again.

Pressing the return key, runs the command, adds it to the history and resets the index to -1.

Answer (score 2):

> **Question**: cycle the elements in a list by pressing `Up`/`Down` arrow key bound to `Entry` widget

Create a `class object` inherited from `tk.Entry`.

```
import tkinter as tk

class EntryHistory(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent, init_history=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.bind('<Return>', self.add)
        self.bind('<Up>', self.up_down)
        self.bind('<Down>', self.up_down)

        self.history = []
        self.last_idx = None

        if init_history:
            for e in init_history:
                self.history.append(e)
            self.last_idx = len(self.history)

    def up_down(self, event):
        if not self.last_idx is None:
            self.delete(0, tk.END)

            if event.keysym == 'Up':
                if self.last_idx > 0:
                    self.last_idx -= 1
                else:
                    self.last_idx = len(self.history) -1
            elif event.keysym == 'Down':
                if self.last_idx < len(self.history) -1:
                    self.last_idx += 1
                else:
                    self.last_idx = 0

            self.insert(0, self.history[self.last_idx])

    def add(self, event):
        self.history.append(self.get())
        self.last_idx = len(self.history) - 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    entry = EntryHistory(root, init_history=['test 1', 'test 2', 'test 3'])
    entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
    root.mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***